# Addition on elliptic curves on finite fields: what if X_1 = X_2 and Y_1 != Y_2?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Given the following curve:

$$ y^3 = x^2 - 7x $$

over the finite field $GF(271)$.

We have $P = (201, 247)$ belongs to the curve:

$$ 247^2 \equiv 201^3 - 7 \cdot 201 \equiv 34 \mod 271 $$

We also have $Q = (201, 24)$ belongs to the curve:

$$ 24^2 \equiv 201^3 - 7 \cdot 201 \equiv 34 \mod 271 $$

So, how to add $R = P+Q$ ? As far as I know, having $m=271$:

- if $P=Q$, then $t = (3x^2+a)/(2y) \mod m$, where $1/(2y) = (2y)^{-1} \mod m$
- if $P \neq Q$, then $t = (y_q - y_p)/(x_q - x_p)$, where $1/(x_q - x_p) = (x_q - x_p)^{-1} \mod m$

Then

$$x_r = t^2 - x_p - x_q \mod m$$

and:

$$y_r = t(x_p-x_r) - y_p \mod m$$

However, in this case we would have division by zero since $P \neq Q$ and $x_p = x_q$.
How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious mistake is the slope. The two points are on the same vertical line. Indeed, $P = -Q$ and their sum is the group identity.

This requires a special case on the Affine Coordinates;

- If $x_1 = x_2 $ and $y_1 = - y_2$, that is $Q =(x_2,y_2)=(x_1,−y_1)=−P$, then $$P+Q = P + (-P) = \mathcal{O}$$

  In your case $247 + 24 = 271$ so $x_1 = x_2$ and $y_1 = -y_1$.

---

**Addendum**

Below is the graph of this curve;

[image]

As we can see, the $P$ and $Q$ are on the same vertical line and have the same distance to the center line ( black)

The Sagemath code for verification and plot of the curve.

```
p = 271
a = -7
b = 0

K = GF(p)
E = EllipticCurve(K,[a,b])
print(E)

P = E(201,247)
Q = E(201,24)
R = P+ Q
print(R)

plotE = E.plot()
plotE += line([(0,136),(272,136)],color='black')
plotE += line([(201,24),(201,247)],color='blue')
plotE += point([201,247], color='red')
plotE += point([201,24], color='red')
plotE += text("P",(201,255), color='red')
plotE += text("Q",(201,18), color='red')

plotE
```

Comment: thanks foir pointing out my mistake! I missed this simple point

Comment: @blackyellow this was not HW, right? I've forgot to ask.

Comment: what I'm doing is trying to implement a program to sign/verify documents using EC

Comment: @blackyellow If what you're doing is not some toy implementation like for a school project, you'll really want to use an existing cryptosystem design if you want it to be secure.